# Can I get the current seed from a Mersenne Twister?

Tags: c++, c, random

I'm adapting a Mersenne Twister in my Application, specifically `mt19937ar.c` from http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html - Code is mirrored on https://gist.github.com/mstum/8367363

This is used as a deterministic RNG in a game, and to make save games work as expected I need to get the current seed out of the MT (rather than the initial seed) so that I can resume.

Example, let's say I initialize it with a seed of `12345` and call `genrand_int31` 5 times. This yields the sequence `1996335345, 1911592690, 679411342, 280691776, 394962642`.

Now, imagine I saved the game after the third number (`679411342`), then reload and get two random numbers. I want these numbers to be the next two numbers (`280691776, 394962642`) of the sequence, and for that I need to know the seed after the third iteration.

As a Workaround, I have the initial seed and the number of times I called into the RNG, so loading a game right now spins up the MT with the initial seed and "replays" `genrand_int31` however many hundreds or thousands of times - which is kinda stupid :)

I tried simply using the first element of the `mt[N]` array, but that really doesn't work. Unfortunately, I don't understand the math behind Mersenne Twister enough to figure out what it actually goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are the status of the MT generator, you may save these and restore it back:

```
static unsigned long mt[N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
static int mti=N+1; /* mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized */
```

Maybe you'll need to modify the original source code in `C`.

Also I don't believe there *exists* any such seed that could be equivalent to *arbitrary* status of the MT: the seed itself contains 64 bits which makes it upto 2^64 possible values, which is far fewer than the status that MT could have (its period is 2^19937-1)

#### EIDTED:

> As a Workaround, I have the initial seed and the number of times I called into the RNG, so loading a game right now spins up the MT with the initial seed and "replays" genrand_int31 however many hundreds or thousands of times - which is kinda stupid :)

Well this is not too stupid. :) Let me tell you that behind the maths of MT, you could recover its internal status of a consecutive period of outputs, and the exact number is 624 -- you'll only need to save the most recent 624 numbers from `genrand_int32`. I'm looking for any existing materials on this.

#### AGAIN EDITED:

[Cracking Random Number Generators - Part 3](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html) shows how to deduce the internal status of a MT generator with some (as few as 624) of its output numbers. That's not quite unexpected since MT is designed for strong statistical randomness but not security as something for crypto.
However I think in this case the simplest way to solve your problem is to add your own code into the MT generator to save/restore its internal status.

Comment: you could pass the return values from genrand_int32 into a vector, but the 'tempering' would need to be moved

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround as well, since that means 625 * 4 Bytes storage, which is perfectly okay (2500 bytes storage)

Comment: That link is awesome, a nice explanation, thanks! For my purposes, saving the entire array and mti is the simplest.

Comment: if saving the entire state isn't practical you could also generate and persist a new seed after every n generations. that way you can keep the number of 'replays' you have to do in control.